# Is there a way to define an array by an argument to a function call?

Tags: c, function, arguments, parameter-passing, definition

I've got a function which expects a variable and a pointer.

```
void sendCMD(byte cmd, byte data[]){
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to call this function with the data in anyway like so

```
sendCMD(0xff, { 0x0a, 0x02 });
```

Since even by googleing I didn't find anything... maybe I haven't looked hard enough, but I'm also not exactly sure what the terms are I should be looking for.
Any help is kindly appreciated!
Note that `byte` is the same thing as a `char`!

Comment: "I've got a function which expects an array. `void sendCMD(byte cmd, byte data[])`" is an improvement over that 2D thing, yet `sendCMD(byte cmd, byte data[])` remains a function that expects a pointer to `byte`, even though `byte data[]`  _looks_ like an array - it is a pointer.

Comment: Just in case it isn't obvious to OP (which given the confusion over "2D" seems plausible), the function parameter `byte data[]` will be automatically adjusted (internally) to `byte *data` by the compiler, and the function will receive a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Ok, I think I got that now and edited the question! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [compound array literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
sendCMD(0xff, (byte[]){ 0x0a, 0x02 });
```